# Laravel 8 Write Cache once on appstart

Tags: laravel, caching

I'd like to write data to the cache once when starting the application. I tried to write the function to the AppServiceProvider, but then the cache is rewritten with each request. what would be a better place or how do you solve such unique calls?

Comment: The way PHP works there's usually no concept of "starting the application" so each request starts in a clean slate. However you could use [Octane](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/octane) with Swoole which behaves more like an application container in the same way tomcat, IIS or Nodejs work for Java, .NET and JavaScript respectively.  You can also check if the cache is populated before populating it on each request if you don't want to start using Octane

Answer (score 0):

Just call in Constructor Method  of Controller when your web start cache ll be clear.

```
\Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
```